# How to Output Color Separations as Vectors from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-separation

My project is to implement a four color design in vinyl  using a cutter/plotter, so each color needs to be cut separately. My plan had been to simply produce a PDF of the separations and send each of those to the cutter. It's been awhile but in a former career I used to do this regularly to create screens for screen printing. But I was stunned to discover that the Adobe PDF printer driver that used to be installed with Acrobat no longer seems to exist on macOS.

Adobe's explanation is that Apple doesn't let them do that anymore and that you shouldn't want to do that anyway since that's the "old way of doing things" without mention what the new way would be. The workaround most people mention is outputting to an Adobe PostScript file which would be fine except you still have to pick a PPD to output separations and once you do you're bound by the physical limitations of that printer (so with most printers I can't create "screens" larger than tabloid size). I considered just trying to find a PPD for a large-format printer (my project is 18"x30"), but those are all inkjet and would therefore output a rasterized separation I think (please correct me if I'm wrong there). I haven't had much luck finding a larger-than tabloid laser printer, but I haven't tried that hard yet. There HAS to be an easier way, right? But even looking around here most of the advice is "Just don't and let someone else handle it." which is wild to me.

I can make them manually if I have to, I'm just having a hard time believing that this foundational  aspect of printmaking has just been so casually abandoned as the realm of only large-scale offset printers entirely.

Comment: Nearly nobody has been doing separations like this for about 20-25 years now. So eventually the burden of updating your software gets to you. When utilitarian technologies die they really die. But realistically doing it manually can be recorded as action so also not a big deal

Comment: For what its worth this method is still available on windows and linux. So this is very much a mac only problem.

Comment: but.. many apps on Win/*Nix need the driver merely to create a PDF.  Such functionality is build into the MacOS itself. I wouldn't really call it a "problem" overall.

Comment: @Scott need is also a opportunity for having better solutions. So not needed is quite otfen also not possible because it is not viable business, Its a tradeoff. So not needed can lead to a problem in corner cases. Does not mean its not a problem.

Comment: I enjoy how every time someone estimates how long "no one has been doing this" it gets longer. We will soon be exceeding the advent of desktop publishing.

Comment: Y'all are arguing about whether this is a real need WHEN I HAVE LITERALLY DESCRIBED A REAL NEED TO YOU. HERE. IN MY QUESTION.

Comment: @grovberg look for a silkscreen mask printers PPD file. Since they output separations the PPD should be good. I was trying to check this out but seems that atleast our more fancy cutters had a feature to do this in their driver software which meant that while our downstairs printshop could do this for me they didnt know any software for it since its all taken care of by the providers of hardware. Silkscreen operators where i am did this directly in the mask printing software but looking online they seem to use one of several external software for this in illustrator. Including inkQuest

Comment: Anyway i am working on a illustrator only answer but i dont have a computer at the moment. So my progress is a bit slow.

Comment: Do you want the separation to also do vector halftoning?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Might help...

Take a look at the [**Astute Graphics InkQuest plug in**](https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/inkquest?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIksOR1cfT9QIVTBXUAR03iwTuEAAYASAAEgLEq_D_BwE) for Illustrator. It's *not* free, but the cost may be worthwhile for the headache it may solve. There *is* a demo I believe so you can try before you buy.

The plug in allows you to generate separations *within Illustrator* (It actually duplicates the open file when you generate seps with it. So you *won't* overwrite anything mistakenly).

[image]

[image]

Then if you use the **`Release Separations`** button on the bottom of the InkQuest panel, you get an independent, single color, layer for each of the plates, essentially digital plates:

[image]

From here, it could possibly be a matter of toggling layer visibility for output.

The InkQuest **magic** is that it splits the actual artwork. It doesn't merely rasterize everything into plate-specific, document-sized, images. It retains vector whenever possible. There **is** some rasterization which may take place, but it's no more than would traditionally happen in a RIP. (Basically there's rasterization when necessary to suit output)

<sub>I am using an older version of the plug it (and Illustrator) here, there may be *more* or *better* features in newer versions.</sub>

---

Original answer:

I'm speculating regarding the driver.

I believe the AdobePDF driver was discontinued because anyone needing to create separations would have an actual correct PPD for their device. Therefore they wouldn't ever need the AdobePDF driver.

And anyone who didn't have an actual PPD wouldn't otherwise need the AdobePDF driver (especially once Apple built a new OS on the foundation of the PDF).

In short, it was *overused* by those who couldn't take advantage of it and *never used* by those which would employ its key features.

To be fair, it's been ... oh, around 15-20 years since it was deprecated. PDF functionality has been built into the operating system, or directly into Adobe applications, since Apple's Snow Leopard (10.6) and Windows 10 releases.

Today.. save as PDF and get proofs from print providers. Or go find that elusive PPD you need.

---

If you have a cutter, you should have a PPD for it. Problem solved.

If you are farming out the cutting, then send a *composite* and let the company doing the cutting separate it. You open the gap for errors by sending pre-separated artwork without knowing the *exact* output environment.

Sending *actual* pre-printed separations, or a file containing individual plates, to anyone for reproduction is indeed the "old way of doing things". In fact, to even think of such a thing means you were doing it quite some time ago, not in the past decade or so. The modern way is to merely send a properly formatted PDF, then whoever is doing the *actual reproduction* traps/separates the PDF to match their environment.

---

<sub>Disclosure: I have no financial interest or stake in Astute Graphics. I make *nothing* should a plug in be purchased. There's no direct affiliation between myself and Astute Graphics. However, in the past, I have received free software from Astute Graphics in exchange for my opinion.</sub>

Comment: Genuine Question: Why does this question make everyone so defensive? Just say you don't know or don't answer the question man.

Comment: Also, why does everyone assume the only way to make something is to send it off? I screen print myself. I will be using the cutter plotter myself. You guys are on some serious "Only the mystical wizards may access this knowledge! Cast not your commoner eyes on the separations!" way of thinking.

Comment: And no, a cutter plotter doesn't have a PostScript Printer Description because it is not a printer. What a weird assumption.

Comment: @grovberg Sorry if I came across defensive. It wasn't intentional. The big issue is that Apple build PDF into the core fo the OS so Adobe figured you no longer need the PDF driver. I wasn't' aware cutters didn't have PPDF files. That seems Odd. But it seems cutter manufacturers have Mac software: https://www.rolanddga.com/support/drivers THere's even a plug in for Illustrator.

Comment: I apologize as well, I'm just getting a lot of "You're wrong for even asking this question." responses in various forums and came in a little hot this morning. The cutter I'm using indeed has a plugin for Illustrator but that's the exact reason this is a problem—I need digital separations that I can open individually in  Illustrator in order to send each one to the cutter via the plugin. I appreciate you taking the time to read the question regardless.

Comment: @grovberg no issue `:)` We've all been there. Check my updated answer... *seems* like a possible solution..

Answer (score 0):

1. The easy way to solve this problem is to just instal the adobe suite on a *windows machine*. Simply because Adobe PDF is available on Windows even if its not available on a OsX. This isnt entriely suprising as one of the main advantages to use Windows is for longterm legacy support.

   If you dont have a new ARM based Mac then you can use a virtual machine with a windows. Your Adobe subscription works on both os so adobe licenses are not a problem. Windows license may be a problem but you can find media for windows machines for virtual computers easily.

   Then simply print, select Adobe PDF as output and as use Adobe PPD and print. It will then ask what PDF file you want to output to.
2. Use the PPD of the cutter

   You can probably copy the Adobe PPD from someone that does have a windows machine it should be cross platform anyway. This would allow you to do the same thing as on windows over the Postscript export. Its not as neat as PDf but should work. Failing that try to get a PPD file for a printer that is designed to output uv masking for screen printing.

   But at least the PPD files of our large inkjets produced a vector result so you could try also a inkjets PPD.
3. use a third party software. There are several with less and more bells and whistles. Generally Astute Graphiucs plugins are good so InkQuest suggested by @Scott is a good solution. There are others.
4. You can do a similar thing in illustrator itself. The downside of this is that it don't support fancy features like overprint, and only easy if you dont have spot colors. You can record an action so you dont need to do this more than once.

   Theres a few different way you can go about this. But i would do it as follows.

   1. Group evefrything.
   2. Expand
   3. Duplicate that group 4 times
   4. Apply Edit -> Edit colors -> Adjust Color Balance.. to every layer

      With all other channels at -100 except the one your processing
   5. (optional) Apply trapping
   6. (optional) Apply Merge on each layer, you can also do this after step 1.

   This can be recordeds o no need to do it more than one time.
5. Let your printshop handle it. It is fine to do this yourself if you are the one printing. But generally the printers producing the cuts will do this for you the benefit of this is that they know how the tolerances and fitting in their machines work so thy can do a much better job than you can.